# Where do I put preprocessor commands when using multiple files?

Tags: c++, include, c-preprocessor

I am doing a project for school using c++, the project is to be split into multiple files.

```
test_driver.cpp - a file to test the code written
storage.cpp - implementation file for storage class and methods
storage.h - header file for storage
song.cpp - implementation file for song class, songs are the data type being manipulated by storage
song.h - header file for song
```

Where do I put my #includes. Storage is dependent on the song data type since it is mostly manipulating them, changing titles, and moving them etc. I'm sorry if this seems like a newb question but I really don't know, and haven't found a solid answer. I would also like to declare a global constant to be shared among the implementation files, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

My view is that every header file should be possible to include without the programmer having to remember what else to include. This isn't always possible to achieve, but I think it's a good rule to aim at.

In other words, if "storage.h" needs something declared in "song.h", then it should include "song.h" - that way, whoever uses "storage.h" doesn't need to also remember the include of "song.h".

If, say, "storage.h" also uses something from "fstream", then it should include "fstream".

In other words, if you include "storage.h" in a file, that's all you should need to do to use the "storage" class.

Comment: Thank you, that is how I feel about it as well, but I'm new to c++ and wasn't sure what the convention was.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (for each cpp file, I am listing the h files you should include inside of it):

```
song.cpp
  song.h

storage.cpp
  storage.h
  song.h
```

Alternatively, if storage.h also depends on song.h (i.e., it uses definitions from it) you could do:

```
storage.h
  song.h

storage.cpp
  storage.h
```

As to the constant, why don't you define a

```
constants.h
```

file and include it where needed?

Comment: and for dependencies like fstream, and iostream, should I include them in the implementation files if necessary? But use the #ifndef preprocessor to ensure nothing is copied more than once? Thank you for the idea constants.h.

Comment: it depends on whether your h files also use definition from streams/iostreams or not; if they do not (or you can forward declare them), then it is best to include the h files only from the cpp file, since it will reduce your dependency graph (see Lakos).